# How to update more than one MongoDB field

Tags: mongodb, go

I am so frustrated with the Official MongoDB for Go. There is really no documentation. I am trying to update more than one field in a collection. All references, as normal are the simplest and updating one field:

```
    update := bson.D{bson.E{"$set", bson.E{"releaseimage", r.ReleaseImage}}}
```

That works. I have tried various ways to expand that to set two fields and get errors:

```
    update := bson.D{
        {"$set",
            bson.E{"releaseimage", r.ReleaseImage},
            //bson.E{"releasepath", r.ReleasePath},
        },
        // {"$set",
        //  bson.E{
        //      "releasepath", r.ReleasePath}},
    }
```

the first one remove the  comments in the first set. invalid syntax for second attempt remove the comments on the second set. invalid syntax.

I am at a loss.  To keep going I am doing two updates, one right after another. Inefficient.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean there's no documentation? [This](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo) looks pretty extensive to me. Is there something specific you feel is missing?

Comment: @flimzy, Thanks for the -1.  It is my opinion the documentation is worthless without good examples. Documentation that says it takes an interface is useless without examples, in my opinion. You may be more advanced than I am, however comments like yours do not help the learning. The one I accepted was  perfect and should be a guide to writers of documentation.

Comment: I could have been more clear in "Really no documentation" to me means nothing useful for beginner/intermediate mongo-go developer. I did state the examples I found "All references, as normal are the simplest and updating one field"  in the various documentation.  

Again the marked answer should be included in some more complete documentation aimed at the beginner/Intermediate developer.

Comment: Hi @DonaldFrench, you can also find examples for MongoDB Go driver on https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/ and select the Go tab above to show the examples in Go. Hope that helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you @ Wan Bachtiar!  That is the type of documentation I was looking for. Based upon the answer I selected I have updates working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple fields, you have to create an array of bson element(`bson.E`). then append/assign as many fields you want in array item.

```
var update []bson.E
if r.ReleaseImage != "" {
    update = append(update, bson.E{"releaseimage", r.ReleaseImage})
}
if r.Releasepath != "" {
    update = append(update, bson.E{"releasepath", r.Releasepath})
}
// now update db
result, err := coll.UpdateOne(
        context.Background(),
        bson.D{
            {"id", r.ID},
        },
        bson.D{
            {"$set", update},
            {"$currentDate", bson.D{
                {"updated", true},
            }},
        },
    )
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Perfect.  This type of information should be part of the documentation. Just saying it is an interface is useless.  Need simple and something more complex.  

I am not sure what you $currentDate is doing though.

Comment: $currentDate for just in case you want to save last update timestamp, the above example will update the field 'updated' with the current timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Simply do like this:

```
uQuery := make(bson.M)
if len(r.ReleaseImage)>0{
  uQuery["releaseimage"]=r.ReleaseImage
}
if len(r.Releasepath)>0{
  uQuery["releasepath"]=r.Releasepath
}
updateQ := make(bson.M)
updateQ["$set"] = uQuery
```

Now simply pass 'updateQ' to mongodb update Wrapper function along with findQuery.